# Onelogin Simple SAML toolkit for PHP

Tags: php, saml, onelogin

I need configure OneLogin SAML toolkit for PHP.

I followed the step for the configuration of SAML toolkit for PHP in [this](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/php) link.

1. I add application SAML Test Connector (IdP w/ attr).
2. I add the content of repository Github to my hosting to run PHP code.
3. I defined the variable in demo1/settings.php

> ```
> 'idp' => array (
>     'entityId' => 'https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/123456',
>     'singleSignOnService' => array (
>         'url' => 'https://app.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/123456',
>     ),
>     'singleLogoutService' => array (
>         'url' => 'https://app.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-redirect/slo/123456',
>     ),
>     'x509cert' => 'XXXXxXXX1xXxXXXxXXXXXXxXXxxXx...',
> )
> ```

4. I copy the configuration from guide to my app in onelogin replaced myapp for my URL hosting
   [image]
5. Now, i going to myhosting/php-saml-master/demo1 and click on Login
   [image]

6.- The URL `myhosting/php-saml-master/demo1` redirect a page mypage.onelogin.com and i write the user and password that i associated the demo1 app but receive this error message

[image]

Please Help! i followed all step in the guide of configuration the Onelogin Simple SAML toolkit for PHP but this not working for me.
any of you can configurate any app in onelogin?

Regards!

Comment: So, you're using an online service and having trouble configuring it. Have you contacted the service provider and asked them for support? SO isn't a generic helpdesk for all services online.

Comment: Alejandro, enable at the advanced settings the debug mode and try to SSO again. You will get the real reason why php-saml rejects OneLogin's SAMLResponse

Comment: And I see that the recipient at Onelogin is wrong, use the same value than the ACS URL

Answer (score 0):

Consumer URL should point to your website (ex. http://localhost/saml_requests) and make sure in you point 3 you use the values from the SSO tab including their certificate.

You can also for starters, initiate the auth from their app, for that make the app available and have the user assigned to it.